# Recursive file search using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am searching for a file in all the folders.

`Copyforbuild.bat` is available in many places, and I would like to search recursively.

```
$File = "V:\Myfolder\**\*.CopyForbuild.bat"
```

How can I do it in PowerShell?

Answer (score 517, accepted):

Use the [Get-ChildItem](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849800.aspx) cmdlet with the `-Recurse` switch:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path V:\Myfolder -Filter CopyForbuild.bat -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force
```

Comment: Seems to have an issue that if it runs into a directory you don't have permission to access, the entire search is aborted because the process exits. Is there a way around that?

Comment: Try to set the ErrorAction parameter to Continue or SilentlyContinue (in case its value is not as mentioned).

Comment: A shorter way of doing exactly the same thing:  
`cd V:\MyFolder` followed by
`ls -r -inc CopyForBuild.bat`

Comment: So what the commenters above mean is... `ls -r -ea silentlycontinue -fo -inc "filename.txt" | % { $_.fullname }`

Comment: I adapted this answer to do partial string by adding the astric symbol (`*`) to the end of the filename.  
******

LINE1: `$File = "Microsoft.OData.Core.NetFX35.V7*"`
LINE2: `$Folder = "C:\Program Files"`
LINE3:`Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder -Filter $File -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force`

Comment: To add to the comments: The diff between `filter` and `inc` is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28603626/1705829). `-fo` could be `force`. `%` is an alias for `foreach-object`

Comment: @OrionEdwards -filter is 2-3x faster than -include.

Comment: @deed02392 I didn't have this problem, at least in ps 5.1.

Comment: @js2010 I'm pretty sure I was on PS 2.0 back in 2013 :-)

Comment: @OrionEdwards: `ls` gives me some `Access to the path '...' is denied` that `Get-ChildItem` don't, but I'm not sure if it is a good thing (it actually searches in said paths) or a bad thing (it does not search in said paths but don't raise an error).

Answer (score 77):

I use this to find files and then have PowerShell display the entire path of the results:

```
dir -Path C:\FolderName -Filter FileName.fileExtension -Recurse | %{$_.FullName}
```

You can always use the wildcard `*` in the `FolderName` and/or `FileName.fileExtension`. For example:

```
dir -Path C:\Folder* -Filter File*.file* -Recurse | %{$_.FullName}
```

The above example will search any folder in the `C:\` drive beginning with the word `Folder`. So if you have a folder named `FolderFoo` and `FolderBar` PowerShell will show results from both of those folders.

The same goes for the file name and file extension. If you want to search for a file with a certain extension, but don't know the name of the file, you can use:

```
dir -Path C:\FolderName -Filter *.fileExtension -Recurse | %{$_.FullName}
```

Or vice versa:

```
dir -Path C:\FolderName -Filter FileName.* -Recurse | %{$_.FullName}
```

Comment: I find this answer extremely useful because it addresses a particular use case - actually wanting to use the file that you are looking for. The | to the give you the full name of the file is something missing in the other answers.

Comment: I have to agree with @Sanity1123 here, if you actually want to use the file, you will need the full path to the file. IMHO this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: As a beginner, I am having troubles understanding what is going on after the pipe. I've opened [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66566918/powershell-syntax) about it.

Comment: As other say, this is the best answer when you need to store the return value. In my case, I had to find a file to remove it, and this made it way easier.

Answer (score 34):

When searching folders where you might get an error based on security (e.g. `C:\Users`), use the following command:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path V:\Myfolder -Filter CopyForbuild.bat -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force
```

Answer (score 23):

Here is the method that I finally came up with after struggling:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path path/with/wildc*rds/ -Include file.*
```

To make the output cleaner (only path), use:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path path/with/wildc*rds/ -Include file.*).fullname
```

To get only the first result, use:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path path/with/wildc*rds/ -Include file.*).fullname | Select -First 1
```

Now for the important stuff:

To search only for files/directories do **not** use `-File` or `-Directory` (see below why). Instead use this for files:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path ./path*/ -Include name* | where {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $false}
```

and remove the `-eq $false` for directories. Do **not** leave a trailing wildcard like `bin/*`.

Why not use the built in switches? They are terrible and remove features randomly. For example, in order to use `-Include` with a file, you must end the path with a wildcard. However, this disables the `-Recurse` switch without telling you:

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -Path ./bin/* -Include *.lib
```

You'd think that would give you all `*.lib`s in all subdirectories, but it only will search top level of `bin`.

In order to search for directories, you can use `-Directory`, but then you must remove the trailing wildcard. For whatever reason, this will not deactivate `-Recurse`. It is for these reasons that I recommend not using the builtin flags.

You can shorten this command considerably:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path ./path*/ -Include name* | where {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $false}
```

becomes

```
gci './path*/' -s -Include 'name*' | where {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $false}
```

- `Get-ChildItem` is aliased to `gci`
- `-Path` is default to position 0, so you can just make first argument path
- `-Recurse` is aliased to `-s`
- `-Include` does not have a shorthand
- Use single quotes for spaces in names/paths, so that you can surround the whole command with double quotes and use it in Command Prompt. Doing it the other way around (surround with single quotes) causes errors

Answer (score 18):

```
Get-ChildItem V:\MyFolder -name -recurse *.CopyForbuild.bat
```

Will also work

Comment: And if you want to output results to a file, you can add ` > path_to_filename.txt` at the end of the command.

Comment: for current directory `Get-ChildItem . -name -recurse *.bat` worked for me

Answer (score 8):

Filter using wildcards:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter CopyForBuild* -Include *.bat,*.cmd -Exclude *.old.cmd,*.old.bat -Recurse
```

Filtering using a regular expression:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "V:\Myfolder" -Recurse
| Where-Object { $_.Name -match '\ACopyForBuild\.[(bat)|(cmd)]\Z' }
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `'\ACopyForBuild\.(bat|cmd)\Z'`?

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path V:\Myfolder -Filter CopyForbuild.bat -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.Attributes -ne "Directory"}
```

Comment: You can also use `| Where-Object { !$_PSIsContainer }` to exclude folders

Answer (score 2):

To add to @user3303020 answer and output the search results into a file, you can run

```
Get-ChildItem V:\MyFolder -name -recurse *.CopyForbuild.bat > path_to_results_filename.txt
```

It may be easier to search for the correct file that way.

Answer (score 0):

On a Windows system:
Search for all .py files in the 'c:\temp' dir and subdirs, type: dir -r *.py or dir *.py -r

On a *Nix (Linux / MacOs system:
at the terminal type: find /temp -name *.py

This works fine for me.

Comment: Not sure why this system blocked me from adding comments.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, robocopy is the fastest and simplest way for searching multiple files in parallel threads. It needs a quite good Powersell code with parallelism to beat that. Here is a link to an article I have written in the past with all the different options you have: [Fastest way to find a full path of a given file via Powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63956318/fastest-way-to-find-a-full-path-of-a-given-file-via-powershell) Check the accepted answer for the best code.