# How do I get the directory of the PowerShell script I execute?

Tags: powershell

I run a PowerShell script. How do I get the directory path of this script I run?

How to do this?

Comment: do you want current working directory of the process?

Comment: No , I want to know which directory contain this script .

Comment: if you know the filename, you can use `get-childItem` to find its path. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8677628/recursive-file-search-using-powershell

Comment: I use get-childItem to get its path , but the result seems contains too much infomation but not just only the path ...

Comment: you need to use some filtering. look at the link i posted in my earlier comment. that might be useful.

Answer (score 175, accepted):

PowerShell 3 has the `$PSScriptRoot` [automatic variable](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx):

> Contains the directory from which a script is being run.
>
> In Windows PowerShell 2.0, this variable is valid only in script modules (.psm1). Beginning in Windows PowerShell 3.0, it is valid in all scripts.

Don't be fooled by the poor wording. `PSScriptRoot` is the directory of the current file.

In PowerShell 2, you can calculate the value of `$PSScriptRoot` yourself:

```
# PowerShell v2
$PSScriptRoot = Split-Path -Parent -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
```

Comment: Why the down vote? Help me make my answer better.  Please provide feedback!

Comment: I'm a bit new to powershell, could you expand on $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition? I see this in many posts and it seems like a placeholder, but for what?

Comment: Agreed: is 'MyCommand.Definition' something I have to type or replace with my script name ? I just tried at the command prompt, and I get nothing back from this ?

Comment: @monojohnny $MyInvocation isn't available at the console, just inside functions and scripts.

Comment: @Sinaesthetic It isn't a placeholder. $MyInvocation is a [System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.invocationinfo.aspx) representing the context the current code was called in. It has all sorts of metadata attached to it.

Comment: Thanks both - I see it works just fine when used from inside a script, thanks !

Comment: @DevisLucato The PowerShell documentation is worded poorly. It sounds like `PSScriptRoot` points to the user's current directory, but in fact `PSScriptRoot` is the directory of the current file.

Comment: A possible 'gotcha', is that if your main script dot-sources scripts on different paths, then $PSScriptRoot will represent the path of the dot-sourced script, whilst that script it executes.