# Difference between -include and -filter in get-childitem

Tags: powershell

Can someone please explain the difference between `-Include` and `-Filter` options in the `Get-ChildItem` command .

Below are the two pieces of code that I am trying to execute . They both serve to find out the text files in a particular directory:

```
PS C:\Users\352997> get-childitem -path Desktop\Extras -filter *.txt


    Directory: C:\Users\352997\Desktop\Extras


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---        12/22/2014   4:05 PM        140 Expense_report.txt
-a---         1/14/2015   4:41 PM        211 Extras.txt
-a---         2/10/2015   2:46 PM        259 Learn Dutch.txt

PS C:\Users\352997> get-childitem -path Desktop\Extras -include *.txt
```

--The above command produces no result ----

Answer (score 30, accepted):

1. `Filter` parameter is implemented by provider. It is efficient because applies when retrieving the objects.
   Get-PSprovider commandlet shows providers that implement 'filter' parameter. For example, there are only two providers on my 
   system:ActiveDirectory and FileSystem
2. `Include` parameter is implemented by Powershell. It only works in conjunction with `Recurse` parameter (as MSDN describes [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem#-include)).
3. It's interesting that:

   ```
   get-childitem -path Desktop\Extras\ -include *.txt
   ```

   returns nothing

   ```
   get-childitem -path Desktop\Extras\* -include *.txt
   ```

   returns list of *.txt files

Maybe these are just nuances of the implementation.

Also see this excellent blog post: http://tfl09.blogspot.com/2012/02/get-childitem-and-theinclude-and-filter.html

Comment: Regarding your bullet point 3.: As stated at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-5.1, 'The -Include parameter is effective only when the command includes the -Recurse parameter or the path leads to the contents of a directory, such as C:\Windows*, where the "*" wildcard character specifies the contents of the C:\Windows directory.'

Comment: So is there any advantage to using `-include` over `-filter`?  I'm starting to wonder if I should just ditch `-include` altogether since `-filter` is lower level and not dependent on `-recurse` or `-path .\*`.  Why does `-include` exist?

Comment: @jschmitter - that actually sounds like another (perhaps good) question - search for a duplicate and if not found ask one :)

Comment: The difference except in perfomance is also in functionality `-filter` only allow for * and ? while `-include` allow for regex like expressions. So it really depends on what and how much you want to filter. They can also be combined, so you might get _some_ of the -Filter performance.

Comment: @Stoinov -include doesn't use regex, I wish it did

Comment: you are correct @js2010. I think I was mislead as _every provider is implementing it on its own_, and I was working with AD at the time. So the correct statement should be that along with better performance, `-filter` could provide more advanced capabilities than the simple include at the cost of added writing complexity.

Comment: buyer beware: Get-ChildItem and Copy-Item on a folder with -Recurse and -Include have different behavior.  The former indeed sees your child items, the latter does not.  ie, `Copy-Item -Recurse -Path myFolder -Include '*.txt' -Destination foo` yields none of the .txt's in there.  I ended up using `Copy-Item -Path (Join-Path myFolder '*.txt') -Destination foo`.

Comment: > "Why does -include exist?"

Get-ChildItem supports multiple providers. However, "The FileSystem provider is the only installed PowerShell provider that supports filters." (from the docs)

Answer (score 0):

`-filter` should be faster than `-include`.  `-filter` can match the short version of filenames in powershell 5.1.