# Powershell script to delete 15 days old .txt files

Tags: powershell, server

I am trying to create a Purgejob in SQL Server server which deletes the .txt files which are older than 15 days.

```
Get-ChildItem –Path  "D:\ABC\Project" -include *.txt –Recurse | Where-Object{$_.CreationTime –lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-15)} | Remove-Item
```

By running this query it is successfully deleting the `.txt` files inside the project folder, but it is also deleting the `subfolder .txt` files which are inside the project folder.  I don't want to delete these files.  All I want is to delete the `.txt` files inside project folder but not in the subfolder of the project folder.

Comment: _"but not in the subfolder"_ than why do you use `-recurse` flag? O_o If you're about to say _"otherwise `-include` does not work"_ you should read this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28600923/difference-between-include-and-filter-in-get-childitem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Remove the recursion and just search in the main folder:

```
Get-ChildItem –Path "D:\ABC\Project\*.txt" | Where-Object{$_.CreationTime –lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-15)} | Remove-Item
```

Comment: Thank you I am going to test this with your suggestion