# Powershell - Searching for files with extension using Get-ChildItem and Read-host

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

Very simple code and I am trying to search for some files with a specific extension using read-host. I then try to pass that to a get-childitem line so search for the said extensions, but its just not working.

```
 $SelectedFiles = Read-Host "Which type of file(s) do you wish to delete?"

 $TargetedLocation = Read-Host "Which location are the files located?"

 Get-ChildItem -Path $TargetedLocation -Include $SelectedFiles -Recurse
```

Comment: That code gets me a list of files just fine. What are you using as input, and what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

I ran this code:

```
$SelectedFiles = Read-Host "Which type of file(s) do you wish to delete?"

$TargetedLocation = Read-Host "Which location are the files located?"

Get-ChildItem -Path $TargetedLocation -Include $SelectedFiles -Recurse
```

Giving the following responses to the prompts:

> Which type of file(s) do you wish to delete?: txt
>
> Which location are the files located?: C:\temp

This returned no output. However, if I repeated with `*.txt`, as the first response, then I do get all of the txt files within `C:\temp`. If you want the end-user to specify the extension without putting `*.` in front then you can do this:

```
$SelectedFiles = Read-Host "Which type of file(s) do you wish to delete?"

$TargetedLocation = Read-Host "Which location are the files located?"

Get-ChildItem -Path $TargetedLocation -Include "*.$SelectedFiles" -Recurse
```

This adds `*.` to the beginning of the response to question 1.

Here's some more context on using `Get-ChildItem` with `-Include`: [Difference between -include and -filter in get-childitem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28600923/difference-between-include-and-filter-in-get-childitem)