# Powershell: Find Folders with (Name) and Foreach Copy to Location Preserve Directory Structure

Tags: powershell

Got another multi-step process I'm looking to streamline. Basically, I'm looking to build a Powershell script to do three things:

1. Get-Childitem to look for folders with a specific name (we'll call it NAME1 as a placeholder)
2. For each folder it finds that has the name, I want it to output the full directory to a TXT file (so that in the end I wind up with a text file that has a list of the results it found, with their full paths; so if it finds folders with "NAME1" in five different subdirectories of the folder I give it, I want the full path beginning with the drive letter and ending with "NAME1")
3. Then I want it to take the list from the TXT file, and copy each file path to another drive and preserve directory structure

So basically, if it searches and finds this:

D:\TEST1\NAME1
D:\TEST7\NAME1
D:\TEST8\NAME1\

That's what I want to appear in the text file.

Then what I want it to do is to go through each line in the text file and plug the value into a Copy-Item (I'm thinking the source directory would get assigned to a variable), so that when it's all said and done, on the second drive I wind up with this:

E:\BACKUP\TEST1\NAME1
E:\BACKUP\TEST7\NAME1
E:\BACKUP\TEST8\NAME1\

So in short, I'm looking for a Get-Childitem that can define a series of paths, which Copy-Item can then use to back them up elsewhere.

I already have one way to do this, but the problem is it seems to copy everything every time, and since one of these drives is an SSD I only want to copy what's new/changed each time (not to mention that would save time when I need to run a backup):

```
$source = "C:\"
$target = "E:\BACKUP\"
$search = "NAME1"
$source_regex = [regex]::escape($source)
(gci $source -recurse | where {-not ($_.psiscontainer)} | select -expand fullname) -match "\\$search\\" |
foreach { 

$file_dest = ($_ | split-path -parent) -replace $source_regex,$target

if (-not (test-path $file_dest)){mkdir $file_dest}
copy-item $_ -Destination $file_dest -force -verbose
}
```

If there's a way to do this that wouldn't require writing out a TXT file each time I'd be all for that, but I don't know a way to do this the way I'm looking for except a Copy-Item.

I'd be very grateful for any help I can get with this. Thanks all!

Comment: You mention "Get-Childitem to look for folders with a specific name" if so then your `gci` is very inefficient, could just do with "search all folders having `Name1` exactly": `gci -Filter Name1 -Recurse -Directory` // aside from that, what is the question? you're asking for help but it's not clear with what

Comment: "Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\" -Filter "*.*" -Recurse | %{$_.FullName}"  (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41836207/724039 )

Comment: You code only copies each time the $seach folder.  You are using -force which will write even when the file or folders exist.  So each time a copy is performed also a check is made to see if folder exists and if not create a new folder.  If you did this a different way you would have to write the code to check if folders exist.  What you have I think is the best method.

Comment: You want to copy only if the new file is newer than the file in the archive.  Since you are using a SSD you only want to copy when the file changes.  So best way is to get a list of files and then copy only when newer.  See following which uses PS and XCopy : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-copy-only-updated-or-newer-files-with-powershell#:~:text=To%20copy%20only%20updated%20or%20newer%20files%20with%20PowerShell%2C%20we,and%20copy%20the%20latest%20file.

Comment: I use a combination of Robocopy and XCopy for various things, but the problem is I've never been able to get them to do exactly what I'm looking for. I want them to find and copy only folders called NAME1, and then copy them to a destination drive while maintaining the directory structure.

Comment: Looks like I found some syntax that does the job: Get-ChildItem $source -Filter *$search* -Name -Recurse | ForEach-Object { robocopy "$source\$_" "$target\$_" /z /s }

Comment: Yes that looks a lot simpler you are overcomplicating it before. `Copy-Item` with `-Recurse` already preserves folder structure. The only problem is using a different folder name for the destination otherwise each name1 folder could be overwritten by a new name1 folder

Comment: I got close with this: "Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Filter *$search* -Name -Recurse | Copy-Item -Destination $target -Recurse"

But it's giving me an error that it can't find the destination file and it's giving the directory of the BAT file I'm running instead of the actual destination folder.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon the way I've got this set up is it specifically preserves the directory structure, so whenever it finds a folder of NAME1 it re-creates the directory structure above it to keep everything separate. I'm doing this to back up files from a specific project so I can copy them to another system and restore them, in effect keeping the entire project portable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to copy all folders with a certain name, keeping the original folder structure in the destination path and copy only files that are newer than what is in the destination already.

Try

```
$source = 'C:\'
$target = 'E:\BACKUP\'
$search = 'NAME1'

# -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue because in the C:\ disk you are bound to get Access Denied on some paths
Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Directory -Recurse -Filter $search -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | ForEach-Object {
    # construct the destination folder path
    $dest = Join-Path -Path $target -ChildPath $_.FullName.Substring($source.Length)
    # copy the folder including its files and subfolders (but not empty subfolders)
    # for more switches see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy
    robocopy $_.FullName $dest  /XO /S /R:0
}
```

<sup>If you don't want console output of robocopy you can silence it by appending `2>&1`, so neither stdout nor stderr is echoed</sup>

If you want to keep a file after this with both the source paths and the destinations, I'd suggest doing

```
$source = 'C:\'
$target = 'E:\BACKUP\'
$search = 'NAME1'
$output = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new()

# -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue because in the C:\ disk you are bound to get Access Denied on some paths
Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Directory -Recurse -Filter $search -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | ForEach-Object {
    # construct the destination folder path
    $dest = Join-Path -Path $target -ChildPath $_.FullName.Substring($source.Length)
    # add an object to the output list
    $output.Add([PsCustomObject]@{Source = $_.FullName; Destination = $dest })
    # copy the folder including its files and subfolders (but not empty subfolders)
    # for more switches see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy
    robocopy $_.FullName $dest  /XO /S /R:0
}
# write the output to csv file
$output | Export-Csv -Path 'E:\backup.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```